# how can I get an json payload of an ec2 instance?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I try to get the json payload of my ec2 instance and I didnt find where can I get it.
I failed to achieve that from the cmd and in the website I didnt find an option to get it

Comment: Install AWS CLI and then run aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <your-instance-ID> and that'll give you data about your ec2 instance. Is that what you are looking for? Here's how to install AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

Comment: What do you mean by "the json payload of my ec2 instance"? What does it contain and where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Instance metadata retrieval from [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)

From that document you can curl via IPv4 or 6 instance metadata with this format:

```
curl -s http://<IPADDRESS>/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
{
  "accountId": "012345678901",
  "architecture": "x86_64",
  "availabilityZone": "eu-central-1c",
  "billingProducts": null,
  "devpayProductCodes": null,
  "marketplaceProductCodes": null,
  "imageId": "ami-01ff76477b9b30d59",
  "instanceId": "i-0b4ae3f67d725bbe7",
  "instanceType": "t3a.nano",
  "kernelId": null,
  "pendingTime": "2022-06-20T09:51:52Z",
  "privateIp": "172.29.40.136",
  "ramdiskId": null,
  "region": "eu-central-1",
  "version": "2017-09-30"
}
```

If you want to list the paths you can curl:

```
curl -s http://<IPADDRESS>/latest/meta-data
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
iam/
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-life-cycle
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

And query one of the paths above:

curl -s http://IPADDRESS/latest/meta-data/METADATA-PATH